# Regex - Matching Abbreviations of a Word

Tags: php, regex, abbreviation

I was thinking in providing the following regex as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110010/how-to-find-wordpresss-installed-on-domain-or-server-provided-whm-api-access), but I can't seem to write the regular expression I was looking for:

```
w?o?r?d?p?r?e?s?s?
```

This should match a ordered abbreviation of the word `wordpress`, but it can also match nothing at all.

How can I modify the above regex in order for it to **match at least 4 chars in order**? Like:

- word
- wrdp
- press
- wordp
- wpress
- wordpress

I'd like to know what is the best way to do this... =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a lookahead assertion:

```
^(?=.{4})w?o?r?d?p?r?e?s?s?$
```

Comment: It seems to find abbreviations out of order like `wodr`.

Comment: Alix it's not exactly clear what abbreviations are ok and which are not: why `wrdp` yes and `wodr` no?

Comment: @kemp: I'm sorry, they both should be okay because the `r` appears twice. `wodw` this one should not be matched. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Alix Axel: Add marks for the start and the end and it works.

Comment: @Gumbo: Thanks, you've a genius! =P

Answer (score 2):

What about php similarity checker functions?

- [levenshtein](http://php.net/levenshtein)
- [similar_text](http://php.net/similar_text)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( strlen($string) >= 4 && preg_match('#^w?o?r?d?p?r?e?s?s?$#', $string) ) {
    // abbreviation ok
}
```

This won't even run the regexp unless the string is at least 4 chars long.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not a regex, just for fun...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

FULLWORD = "wordprocess"

def check_word(word):
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(word) and j < len(FULLWORD):
        if word[i] == FULLWORD[j]:
            i += 1; j += 1
        else:
            j += 1

    if j >= len(FULLWORD) or i < 4 or i >= len(FULLWORD):
        return "%s: FAIL" % word
    return "%s: SUCC" % word

print check_word("wd")
print check_word("wdps")
print check_word("wsdp")
print check_word("wordprocessr")
```